# Simple transparent plastic shelf and noise

Tags: modeling, shaders

How can I get the effect of transparent white plastic or glass? When I tried the shaders received white noise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: More information would be helpful... What render engine are you using? Maybe upload your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: I use blender cycles. Can't upload file. I upload light path settings. And in model i have diffuse + transparent connect to mix shader.

Comment: It's hard to help without more information. An image of your node set up at least. Also, I'm guessing using more "Samples" in your render would help your render...

Comment: You can always use the glass shader that should give you the results you want. then increase your samples up a bit. You can find the samples in the render panel. If you need any help with anything please, just ask.